# what is the best way to sort index and value of number of items

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, hashmap

I have the following business requirement
I have value1 and value2 pairs for an object and I need to save value1 and value2 in a sorted data structure according to value 2.

What I have done is making an array of hashmaps so that each element in the array contains a hasmap of two elements; value1 and value2. but I am stuck in the sorting mechanism, i need to sort the array according to the second value (value2)

Example

```
HashMap[] array = new HashMap[100]();

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   array [i].put("value1", value1);
   array [i].put("value2", value2);
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to store this so I want the best data structure to use and sort accordingly but the main thing that I need to keep track of value1 so that it stick with value2 when sorting according to value2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to keep track of value1 so that it stick with value2 when sorting according to value2

@Thomas may be right that what you need is a sorted map.  The limitation there is that `SortedMap` only sorts by the keys of the map which have to be unique.  You can't put two things into the map with the same `value2` contents.

An alternative is to create an object to encapsulate your two values.  That's how we often do things in an object oriented language.

```
private static class ValueWrapper {
    private final String value1;
    private final String value2;
    public ValueWrapper(String value1, String value2) { 
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a collection of these:

```
List<ValueWrapper> wrappers = new ArrayList<>();
wrappers.add(new ValueWrapper("1", "a"));
wrappers.add(new ValueWrapper("2", "b"));
```

If you want to sort them, you can either make the object itself implement `Comparable` or sort it using an external `Comparator`.  So you could change the object:

```
private static class ValueWrapper implements Comparable<ValueWrapper> {
    private final String value1;
    private final String value2;
    public ValueWrapper(String value1, String value2) { 
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
    public int compareTo(ValueWrapper other) {
        // we are comparing the value2 fields here
        return this.value2.compareTo(other.value2);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<ValueWrapper> wrappers = new ArrayList<>();
wrappers.add(new ValueWrapper("1", "a"));
wrappers.add(new ValueWrapper("2", "b"));
// this sorts objects that implement Comparable
Collections.sort(wrappers);
```

As an alternative, you can provide an external `Comparator` class.  This is useful if you sort the list in different ways:

```
// this uses an anonymous Comparator class but you can define a class to do it
Collections.sort(wrappers, new Comparator<ValueWrapper>() {
     public int compare(ValueWrapper o1, ValueWrapper o2) {
         return o1.value2.compareTo(o2.value2);
     }
});
```

You can then define a couple different `Comparator` classes, each comparing the `ValueWrapper` in different ways.

Comment: Thanks. you are right I might need to put two things into the map with the same value2 contents

Comment: I have the values in a encapsulated objects already (value1 is actually a private attribute in a class). how can use the above without ValueWrapper class?

Comment: You then put the class with the value1 attribute into a collection and either make your class implement `Comparable` or write a `Comparator` for your class.  See my example code above @user3631926.

Comment: Thanks. This helped alot

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) implementation instead, probably a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

```
SortedMap<String, String> values = new TreeMap<String, String>();
values.put(value2, value1); // value2 is the "key", value1 is the "value"
```

Comment: Thanks. what about the sorting?

Comment: A `SortedMap` sorts by its keys automatically. That's the whole point of using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... why am I getting -1 on the question? do you have an idea?

Comment: how can I get an item according to a specific index (like getting the 5th item from the sorted map)?

Comment: You can't, at least not efficiently. That requirement was not mentioned in the question and mostly invalidates this answer... You can use an `ArrayList` of pairs instead, either writing your own `Pair` class or taking it from e.g. Guava.

Answer (score 0):

according to java doc "it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time " so if sort this HashMap may change it order ,i recommend to use class to store data in it,

`public class test {
    public type1 a;
    public  type2 b;
}`

so you can use default java sorting algorithm like this

```
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<test>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(test o1, test o2) {
        if(o1.a>o2.a)return 1;
        else if(o1.a==o2.a)return 0;
        return -1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's implement a helper class which `implements` `Comparator`:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(HashMap[] a, HashMap b) {
        String aVal = a.get("value2");
        String bVal = b.get("value2");
        if ((aVal == null) || (bVal == null)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return aVal.compareTo(bVal);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Arrays.sort(array, new MyComparator());
```